# Unflagging a Post I Flagged

Tags: discussion

If I flag a post, then I re-read it, and decide that I think it does fit into the site, how do I un- flag the post?

Comment: Generally, in the SE sites you cannot unflag a post you've flagged

Comment: The general advice from SE is "be more careful with your flags", but mistakes do happen (in which case luser droog's answer is good).

Comment: OK.  I'll do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the best you can do is raise another flag, select "other", and explain what's changed. The mod will see all the flags on the post in a list, so just explain whatever needs explaining. They'll get the message.

Comment: Yep - we're reasonably intelligent, so a wee note will let us know :-)