# Unable to retract a flag

Tags: support, flagging

I flagged an answer as "not an answer". The flag is currently "disputed", and after a second look, I realize my initial flag was in error. However, I'm not able to find a way to retract the flag.

As I understand it, I should be able to click the 'flag' link again, and a "retract" button will appear in the dialog. However, there is no such button.

Am I doing something wrong? Does the feature not apply to MP&T? Are there conditions where a flag cannot be retracted? Something else?

Related questions:

- Meta post confirming the feature: [Cancel misclicked flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags)
- Post on MP&T meta with a pre-retraction feature solution: [Unflagging a Post I Flagged](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2219/unflagging-a-post-i-flagged)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only retract flags which are still pending. Disputed is one of the final outcomes (helpful and declined are the most common ones), and in the case of a Not An Answer flag indicates that the Low Quality Posts review ended up in favor of the post not being deleted.

You don't need to worry, disputed flags [don't count towards a flag ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243687/295232) and as indicated above, the post itself won't be punished either.